# Querying a string from int column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ids` (
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

It contains some IDs: 111, 112, 113, 114 etc.

I made a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ids` WHERE id = '112abcdefg'
```

I expected nothing but I've got a result, a row with ID of 112. Seems that MySQL quietly converted my string to integer and then compared it against column values.

How can I change the query so that querying the same string from `id` column will give no results as I expect? Is there a strict comparison modifier in MySQL?

Comment: Extract the number *before* you do your query

Comment: Fun reading: http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to `CAST` the `112` to `CHAR` to get a proper match:

```
WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR(12)) = '112abcdefg'
```

The `12` in `CHAR` is a guess; it should be large enough for your biggest `id`.

That will probably kill any chance of optimization, so another option (though one I'm not 100% sure of) is to use a `BINARY` comparison. I've tried this with a few different values and it works:

```
WHERE BINARY id = '112abcdefg'
```

Comment: I think the proper usage is `cast(id as char(12))`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @chuex - a case of "typing while distracted" :)

Comment: +1 you just beat me to this one. I kept trying to cast as varchar, but it kept complaining. (I'm not a MySQL guy).

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing a string, just put the number with no quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `ids` WHERE id = 112
```

If you dont, it will convert the string '112abcdefg' to a number and say its 112

The response you are seeing is because you are trying to compare an integer column to a string value. In that case, MySQL will type-cast the string literal value to an integer, and when it does that it starts from the left of the string and as soon as it reaches a character that cannot be considered part of a number, it strips out everything from that point on. So trying to compare "256abcd" to an integer column will result in actually comparing the number 256.

So your options (or at least a few of them) would be:
Validate the input string in your application code and reject it if it's not an integer (see the ctype_digit function in PHP).
Change the column type for the filename if you want to treat it as a string (e.g. a VARCHAR type).
Cast the column value to a string:

```
. . . WHERE CAST(Id AS CHAR) = '256aei'
```

[Source](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?198533-MySQL-select-where-clause-truncates-strings-beginning-with-ints)

Comment: You probably misunderstood my question.

Comment: So you pretend to compare an int and a string and get results?
SQL is parsing that string when it should just crash saying its wrong.

Comment: Exactly the opposite, I want to get no results, but it gives me results.

Answer (score 2):

lame + kills optimization but serves it purpose

```
SELECT * FROM `ids` WHERE concat(id) = '112abcdefg';
```

that way you enforce casting to string
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
SET sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES;
```

this sets you sql mode to strict checking, and then try firing the query you mentioned.

Comment: I'll try this, but I prefer a query-level solution, don't want to mess up the whole application.