# mysql query compare string with int value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make select query as follow

```
SELECT * FROM `corporate_names` WHERE id = '1s';
```

but it still gives me result as there is no column id with value equals to '1s'.
it reslts me of `SELECT * FROM corporate_names WHERE id = '1';` result.

I am not getting why isthis happening? how can i exactly match `id` column with string value as id is primary key with int column type.

i want it to exact match the column value

Comment: '1s' will never match an integer column. Your question is very unclear. With your rep at 188, you should know how to ask a question. Check out the links in my next comment for some helpful information.,

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i just want to match '1s' with column id, and it is giving me result where id=1, it should not give result as we know id column can not have value '1s', i want it to exact match

Comment: If you tell MySQL to compare an integer and a string *and don't tell MySQL what to do*, it has three options: a) convert the integer to a string and compare as a string b) make an attempt to convert the string to an integer (with several sub-options like remove all non-digit things, treat a string as a flat 0, ...) and compare as an integer c) throw an error. You know now what MySQL chose. If you do not like that choice: tell MySQL what you want. In this case, cast the id to a string. Alternatives are e.g. to check if your input is a valid integer and not executing that query at all.

Comment: @Solarflare thank you. your comment was helpful. i did it as `SELECT * FROM corporate_names where CAST(id as char(255)) = '1s'`. thank you.

Comment: Some clever people above suggesting to read Stack Overflow manual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying a string from int column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820974/querying-a-string-from-int-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this as below

```
SELECT * FROM `corporate_names` where CAST(id as char(255)) = '1s'.
```

now it is exactly matching value with column value, i just cast id column to char.

Answer (score 3):

When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa. 
example

```
SELECT 1+'1'; -> 2
```

The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:

For details you can read [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

**But you can stop it following way**

```
SELECT case when  CONVERT('1s' USING utf8) = cast( 1 as char) then 2 else 0 end; this will return 0 .
```

**so explicit conversion is the way of stopping this or solving your problem**

Comment: @VishalB  i checked a lot of documentation of mysql and found only explicit conversion is the way of solving your peoblem

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to get all the corporate names where the id starts with 1 then use LIKE as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM `corporate_names` WHERE id LIKE '1%';
```

Else if you would like to retrieve the results for just a specific id use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `corporate_names` WHERE id='1';
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i want it to exact match, as if column has value '1s' give result otherwise not, but it is giving me result as 'id' column does not has value '1s'.

Comment: @VishalB It should give you nothing if it does not countain 1s. It should say 0 row(s) returned. You should be using the query SELECT * FROM `corporate_names` WHERE id='1s'; to accomplish ths

Comment: thats the question says.. in my query id = 1s but it still giving me result

Comment: `SELECT * FROM corporate_names WHERE id LIKE  '1s';`