# How to find a string data from a column which is integer type?

Tags: sql-server

The column in my table are of integer type but some values are like 24/3 or 488-89 or may be other  which are behaving like varchar ?  so how can i find such data from that column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying a string from int column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820974/querying-a-string-from-int-column)

Comment: There is no `integer` type in SQL Server (do you mean `int`)? It is *not possible* to store a value like `24/3` or `488-89` in an `int` column. Please provide a [mcve], including the table schema.

Comment: *"The column in my table are of integer type"* and *"but some values are like 24/3 or 488-89"* are conflicting statements. You cannot store the value `24/3` in an `int` datatype. If you passed `24/3` as an expression it would be calculated and stored as `8`. If you passed the literal string `'24/3'` you would get a conversion error. Either way, what you describe you are doing and what you are *actually* doing are not the same.

Comment: Agreed this doesn't make sense. If, somewhere, you are seeing values like `24/3` or `488-89`, then they cannot be coming directly from an `int` field. Either they come from elsewhere, or there is some code in between which is manipulating or adding to those values to create that output. You need to explain how and where you are seeing this data, and what code is used to produce it.

Answer (score 1):

If your column is of `INT` data type, then there is no way to store non `INT` values. Assuming that your column is actually of `VARCHAR` and you tried to store `INT` values and sometimes you inserted something else, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` to see which aren't convertible to `INT`.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS T WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, T.MyColumn) IS NULL
```

`TRY_CONVERT` is available from SQL Server 2012+, if you have 2008 you can use a `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS T WHERE T.MyColumn NOT LIKE '%^[0-9]%'
```