# Laravel query getting data even it doesn't match

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, get

I have created a get request function that gets the id from the url `http://localhost/user/list?id=1`. And now as per testing, even though it has characters like `http://localhost/user/list?id=1DFasdf`, it retrieves the data values of column 1. I'm a bit confused to this one since I'm new to this issue:

```
public function lists(Request $request)
{
    // $id value is 1 or 1DFasdf
    $id = $request->id;
    dd($this->roomList->where('id', $id)->get());
}
```

so when I display the result with or without the dummy characters, it retrieves the data of column 1, but if I use other id (that is not existing in db) or characters first, it works as expected. How can I prevent this one from happening?

Comment: What is assigned to `$this->roomList` does it already contain some query setup ?

Comment: @Mike It's a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about type juggling:-

```
public function lists(Request $request)
{
    // $id value is 1 or 1DFasdf
    $id = $request->id;
    dd($this->roomList->where('id','like', $id)->get());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL considers the value as integer for field type is integer for e.g

if id = 2 and you enter id = "2test" the output will be the id match in the database,
but if you put id = "test2" then it will returns nothing.

Also you can check the same thing in MySQL query.

[Please check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820974/querying-a-string-from-int-column).

if you need to match exactly then first you need to cast that field as char in laravel.

```
$this->roomList->whereRaw("CAST(id AS CHAR(12))", $id)->get()
```